# Make URL start select dropdown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have two select box (dropdown) and I need to create a url starting these dropdowns. example:

```
<form name="states_cities">
<select name="states">
<option value="ac">Acre</option>
<option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option>
<option value="sp">São Paulo</option>
<option value="to">Tocantis</option>
</select>

<!-- cities of "Rio de Janeiro" -->
<select name="cities"> 
<option value="queimados">Queimados</option>
<option value="volta-redonda">Volta Redonda</option>
<option value="nova-iguacu">Nova Iguaçú</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

And i need make this url example:

http://ValueState.ValueCity.domain.com or
http://rj.queimados.domain.com

when the user clicks GO!

what better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get selected options you should use jQuery [:selected selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) this way:

```js
$('#go').on('click', function(){
    var city = $('#cities option:selected').text();
    var state = $('#states option:selected').text();
    var newLocation = 'http://' + state + '.' + city + '.domain.com';
    // window.location = newLocation;
    alert(newLocation);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="states" id="states">
    <option value="ac">Acre</option>
    <option value="rj">Rio de Janeiro</option>
    <option value="sp">São Paulo</option>
    <option value="to">Tocantis</option>
</select>

<!-- cities of "Rio de Janeiro" -->
<select name="cities" id="cities"> 
    <option value="queimados">Queimados</option>
    <option value="volta-redonda">Volta Redonda</option>
    <option value="nova-iguacu">Nova Iguaçú</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" id="go">Go</button>
```

Comment: Hi! I tested here, and this way he does so in url:


domain.com?state=rj&city=volta-redonda


strange, since reading the code seemed to work.

Comment: Just one correction: rather than text() - val() should be used:  var city = $('#cities option:selected').val();
    var state = $('#states option:selected').val();

Comment: **TheDude, Skobaljic and Nevermind**, thanks! 

I was putting the script above jquery, for it was not working. Put down and it worked perfectly. Thank U!

Comment: Hi again! how to change commom button to submit? 
when i insert submit button don't work, make **domain.com?state=rj&city=rio-de-janeiro**

Comment: @VitordeSousa, prevent default action of submit button (or make type=button"), and redirect by javascript.

Answer (score 1):

iF you would like to use jquery library, please try this, demo @ **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/User86745458/692zq3vj/)**

**JS**

```
$('#go').on('click', function(){
    var state = $('[name="states"] :selected').val();
    var city = $('[name="cities"] :selected').val();
    var url = 'http://' + state + '.' + city + '.domain.com?state=' + state +'&city=' + city;
    alert(url);
    window.location = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function make_url() {
states = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0];
selected_state = states.options[states.selectedIndex].value;
cities = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[1];
selected_city = cities.options[cities.selectedIndex].value;

    url='http://'+selected_state+'.'+selected_city+'.'+'domain.com';
alert(url);    

}

go=document.getElementById('go');
go.addEventListener('click',make_url);
```

Vanilla js... demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ofkLxy0r/